# android remove or recycle images from gallery? Is it possible?

Tags: android

android remove or recycle images from gallery? Is it possible?

How Can i do this? (g is my gallery view)

I tried this:

```
private void exit() {
    g.setAdapter(null);

    for (int i=0; i< imgadapter.images.size(); i++) {
        if (imgadapter.images.get(i)!=null) {
            imgadapter.images.get(i).recycle();
            imgadapter.images.set(i, null);
        }
    }
    imgadapter.images.clear();
    System.gc();
}


08-05 09:09:19.671: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1279): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-05 09:09:19.671: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1279):     at android.widget.Gallery.makeAndAddView(Gallery.java:748)
08-05 09:09:19.671: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1279):     at android.widget.Gallery.layout(Gallery.java:625)
08-05 09:09:19.671: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1279):     at android.widget.Gallery.onLayout(Gallery.java:339)
08-05 09:09:19.671: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1279):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7228)
08-05 09:09:19.671: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1279):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
08-05 09:09:19.671: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1279):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7228)
08-05 09:09:19.671: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1279):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
08-05 09:09:19.671: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1279):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7228)
08-05 09:09:19.671: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1279):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
08-05 09:09:19.671: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1279):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7228)
08-05 09:09:19.671: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1279):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1145)
08-05 09:09:19.671: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1279):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1865)
08-05 09:09:19.671: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1279):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-05 09:09:19.671: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1279):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-05 09:09:19.671: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1279):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
08-05 09:09:19.671: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1279):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 09:09:19.671: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1279):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-05 09:09:19.671: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1279):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
08-05 09:09:19.671: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1279):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
08-05 09:09:19.671: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1279):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably not a good idea to carpet-bomb your adapter and delete everything, regardless of whether or not it's still in use. `recycle` is merciless and will delete your bitmap, even if it's still in use.

Since you're using a Gallery, I would make use of Android's built-in recycling mechanism for adapters.

See how `Adapter.getView` takes a `View` parameter. If that's not null, you are recycling an old view. That's the perfect place for you to grab the bitmap from that old view (which you know will not be used anymore!) and recycle it. You can then use that view and re-populate it (rather than creating a new one).

Comment: The recycling code in Android's Gallery class is broken. Not sure if they have fixed it, but it is still broken in eclair: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3376

Comment: Looks like it is still broken in ICS